# How to get the list of deployed application with XL Deploy Api

Tags: api, xl-deploy

How can I get the list of deployed application with XL Deploy REST Api, with their duration.

I've searched on the doc https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/8.6.x/rest-api/index.html
I get find the request for my need, perhaps I am not searching at the right place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the list of all deployed application using this endpoint: https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/8.6.x/rest-api/com.xebialabs.deployit.engine.api.RepositoryService.html#/repository/query:GET

With a query like: http://user:password@yourXLD/deployit/repository/query?type=udm.DeployedApplication&ancestor=Environments&resultsPerPage=-1

As for the durations of the deployment, surely a little bit tricky, I think it should be in the TaskBlockService (https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/8.6.x/rest-api/com.xebialabs.deployit.engine.api.TaskBlockService.html). You can also try to monitor with your browser the http requests issued by the webUI, we have been able to get some API endpoints that were not documented... Needless to say it won't be officialy supported.